# Webdriverjs get data attribute

Tags: javascript, webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor to write my tests and when I search the attribute of an element it works except with "data-" attributes:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('.wrap.loaded'))
                .then(function(thumb) {
                    thumb.getAttribute('data-width')
                        .then(function(w) {
                      ... //*w == null*
                });
});
```

As I said, if I have a non data attribute, it works fine:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('.wrap.loaded'))
                .then(function(thumb) {
                    thumb.getAttribute('class')
                        .then(function(c) {
                      ... //*c == wrap loaded*
                });
});
```

Does anyone know why it happens and if there is a way to get the data attributes from a Wedriver.WebElement in javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Just for the purpose of debugging, [get all element's attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694570/get-all-element-attributes-using-protractor) and post what are you getting. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but as a good practice, stop using `ptor.findElement`. Instead use: `$('.wrap.loaded').getAttribute('class').then(function(c) {//do something with c});`

Comment: Do you mean using JQuery on my tests?